# How to redirect all *.html pages to *.php pages?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, redirect

I looked for the answer to this since it should be a rather common thing to do
and found some but the all lead me to an internal server error.. :(
i need to redirect all my html pages to their counter part in php

i know there is a rewriteRule i can use but cant seem to find the syntax..

**a simple explenation:**
i need to redirect all my *.html pages to *.php

I hope i explained it well.. would love your help or a link to some resources on this subject where i can really understand how to create this redirectRule

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a `.htaccess` in the root folder of your site and place the following rules in it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [L,R]
```

If you don't want the address bar to reflect the change, then change that last line to

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ $1.php [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)\.html$ $1.php [R]
```

If you get Internal Server Errors, make sure that you have enabled mod_rewrite in apache :

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```